# How to load object into Laravel 5.5 Mailable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to test a mailable class for a Laravel 5.5 application, and have seemingly followed all the directions [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail).

I've been trying to [preview my mailable in the browser](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#previewing-mailables-in-the-browser), but for some reason the object that I pass to my mailable class is not passing correctly, and is showing as null from inside the mailable class even though I can see that it exists outside of it.

Here is the function in my `web.php` file that I'm using to test the mailable in the browser:

```
Route::get('/testingMailable', function () {
    $review = App\EvaluationReview::find(6);
    return new App\Mail\StartReview($review);
});
```

The object is populating as it should above, but when I try to view it inside the mailable class, it is null:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\EvaluationReview;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class StartReview extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $review;

    public function __construct(EvaluationReview $review)
    {
        $this->$review = $review;
        dd($this->review);//is null
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('test@test.com')->view('startReview');
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the object is not getting passed into the mailable class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

**Change:**

```
    $this->$review = $review;
```

**To:**

```
    $this->review = $review;
```